# Google compute engine only starting at night

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-compute-engine

I am trying to start an instance of google compute engine with jupyter notebook but I am only able to connect to it at night and am not sure what could be the issue. (I do the exact same things to start the instances between doing it at night and during the same)

Thoughts:
How does google tell us for preemptible instances if all machines are at full capacity? I am using preemptible instances so I was thinking it may be that during the day google has been full every time I try. (Seems like an unlikely scenario though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was mainly because the network at my office (firewall I presume) was obstructing my connection, so only when I was at home in the evening I was able to log in.

Answer (score 0):

Try launching your preemptible instance in a different zone in [another region](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/), even another continent - where there is night is at the moment. For example, if it is a day in the U.S., you could launch your preemptible VM in a European zone.

Preemptible VMs could indeed be utilized more during day time as people use them to do their daily jobs.